Toasts not showing
I trying to show the toast after the request of change status of the device is completed. Everthing is fine about he request and the states really change. But after the states change, I trying to show the toast indicating the success processing. But anything is showed.
Here is the code:
Toast.js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import {
    CToaster,
    CToast,
    CToastHeader,
    CToastBody
} from '@coreui/react';

const Toast = ({ header, body }) => (
    <CToast>
      <CToastHeader closeButton>
        {header}
        </CToastHeader>
      <CToastBody>{body}</CToastBody>
    </CToast>
  );

  export default Toast

Dashboard.js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import axiosService from '../../services/axiosService'
import Toast from '../../components/Toast';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
    CButton, 
    CButtonGroup, 
    CCard, 
    CCardBody, 
    CCol, 
    CRow, 
    CTable,
    CTableHead,
    CTableRow,
    CTableHeaderCell,
    CTableBody,
    CTableDataCell,
    CModal,
    CModalHeader,
    CModalFooter,
    CModalTitle,
    CModalBody,
    CToaster,
    CToast,
    CToastHeader,
    CToastBody
} from '@coreui/react';
import { cilCheckCircle, cilChart, cilCog, cilX, cilWarning } from '@coreui/icons';
import WidgetsDropdown from '../widgets/WidgetsDropdown';
import WidgetsBrand from '../widgets/WidgetsBrand';

import CIcon from '@coreui/icons-react';

const Dashboard = () => {
    const [devices, setDevices] = useState([]);
    const [visibleDelete, setVisibleDelete] = useState(false);
    const [visibleStatus, setVisibleStatus] = useState(false);
    const [deviceToDelete, setDeviceToDelete] = useState({}); // Estado para armazenar temporariamente o dispositivo a ser excluído
    const [deviceToStatus, setDeviceToStatus] = useState({});
    const navigate = useNavigate(); // Inicialize o useNavigate
    const [toasts, setToasts] = useState([]);

    const showToast = (header, body) => {
        const newToast = { header, body, id: Date.now() };
        setToasts(prevToasts => [...prevToasts, newToast]);

        // Remove o toast após 5 segundos
        setTimeout(() => {
            setToasts(prevToasts => prevToasts.filter(toast => toast.id !== newToast.id));
        }, 5000);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        axiosService.get(`${import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL}/devices`)
            .then(response => {
                // Verificando se a resposta possui a propriedade "dispositivos"
                if (response && response.dispositivos) {
                    setDevices(response.dispositivos);
                } else {
                    console.error('Error fetching devices: Data structure is not as expected.');
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching devices:', error);
            });
    }, []);
    const handleSubmitStatus = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axiosService.put(`${import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL}/device/${deviceToStatus.id}`)
            .then(response => {
                // Verifica se a resposta da API foi bem-sucedida
                if (response.resultado) {
                    // Atualiza o estado dos dispositivos
                    setDevices(prevDevices => {
                        // Mapeia os dispositivos antigos e atualiza apenas o dispositivo modificado
                        return prevDevices.map(device => {
                            if (device.id === deviceToStatus.id) {
                                // Atualiza apenas o status do dispositivo alterado
                                return { ...device, status: deviceToStatus.status === 1 ? 0 : 1 };
                            } else {
                                return device;
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    // Fecha o modal após a alteração bem-sucedida
                    setVisibleStatus(false);
                    showToast("Sucesso", "O status do dispositivo foi atualizado com sucesso.");

                } else {
                    console.error('Error updating device status: Unexpected response data');
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error updating device status:', error);
            });
    };
    // Função para navegar para a página do dispositivo com os dados do dispositivo selecionado
    const goToDevicePage = (deviceId) => {
        navigate(`/device/panel/${deviceId}`, { replace: true });
    };

    // Função para configurar o dispositivo a ser excluído e mostrar o modal
    const handleDeleteDevice = (device) => {
        setDeviceToDelete(device);
        setVisibleDelete(true);
    };

    // Função para configurar o dispositivo a ter seu status alterado e mostrar o modal de mudança de status
    const handleStatusChange = (device) => {
        setDeviceToStatus(device); // Configura o dispositivo para o qual o status será alterado
        setVisibleStatus(true); // Mostra o modal de mudança de status
    };

    return (
        <>

        <CToaster position="top-right">
            {toasts.map(toast => (
                <Toast key={toast.id} header={toast.header} body={toast.body} />
            ))}
        </CToaster>


try checking on response response.data for the condition to show the toast in axios the return data is in that key and add the visible property to the toast
if (response.data || response.data.resultado) {
    .....
    showToast("Sucesso", "O status do dispositivo foi atualizado com 
    sucesso.")
 }

const Toast = ({ header, body ,visible}) => (
<CToast animation={true} autohide={true} visible={visible}>
  <CToastHeader closeButton>
    {header}
    </CToastHeader>
  <CToastBody>{body}</CToastBody>
</CToast>

);
 <CToaster position="top-right">
        {toasts.map(toast => (
            <Toast key={toast.id} header={toast.header} body={toast.body} visisble={true}/>
        ))}
    </CToaster>


I tried but still not showing. The documentation is here but I don't undestand verywell:
https://coreui.io/react/docs/components/toast/

you are not managing the toast well based on the documentation provide it await a prop name  autohide={true} visible={true} that will control if the toast is show or not and you should also add position on the toast like position="top-right"
